# Specifying height in xml layout root view fail

Tags: android

Say I have a custom layout xml,and set its root view's height to 300dp.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is text"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="click me"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Later I inflate it and add it to another view container.

```
LinearLayout customView = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view_layout,null);

viewContainer.addView(customView);
```

However,the customView's height is not 300dp.Where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `android:minHeight="300dp"` Then android will ensure minimum 300dp.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are using **wrap content** for Textview and Button's height, so the layout height can not be 300dp because there are some spaces missing. You should define your attributes height too, instead of wrap content.

I usually use **match parent** as my layout height, and **set the height for attributes which are inside**..

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:text="This is text"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:text="click me"/>

</LinearLayout>
```